# Getting PK from another table that isn't user - Django REST framework

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I need help with the following problem please. I've managed to connect a user's id to another table, but I can't seem to replicate the same process when connecting a table to another's primary key. What am I doing wrong?

**MODEL**

*Parent model*

```
class TestDataTwo(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField("auth.User", related_name="testdatatwo", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
test_name = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True, default="N/A")
```

*Child model*

```
class TestDataThree(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField("auth.User", related_name="testdatathree", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
sdgdata = models.OneToOneField(TestDataTwo, related_name="testdatatwo", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=-1)
test_name_again = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=True, default="N/A")
```

**SERIALIZER**

*Parent serializer*

```
class TestDataTwoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = TestDataTwo
    fields = (
        "id",
        "user_id",
        "test_name",
    )
```

*Child serializer*

```
class TestDataThreeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = TestDataThree
    fields = (
        "id",
        "user_id",
        "test_name_again",
    )
```

**VIEW**

*Parent serializer*

```
class TestDataTwoViewSet(ModelViewSet):
queryset = TestDataTwo.objects.all().order_by('id')
serializer_class = TestDataTwoSerializer
paginator = None

# CREATE NEW TESTDATATWO ROW FOR USER
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

# GET ALL ENTRIES OF TESTDATATWO FOR SPECIFIC USER, EXCEPT IF SUPERUSER, THEN RETURN ALL
def get_queryset(self):
    # if self.request.user.is_superuser:
    #     return self.queryset
    # else:
    return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)

# PUT/PATCH
def perform_update(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

# DELETE TESTDATATWO ID
def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object()
    self.perform_destroy(instance)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

*Child serializer*

```
class TestDataThreeViewSet(ModelViewSet):
queryset = TestDataThree.objects.all().order_by('id')
serializer_class = TestDataThreeSerializer
paginator = None

# CREATE NEW TESTDATATHREE ROW FOR USER
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

# GET ALL ENTRIES OF TESTDATATHREE FOR SPECIFIC USER, EXCEPT IF SUPERUSER (THEN RETURN ALL INSTEAD)
def get_queryset(self):
    # if self.request.user.is_superuser:
    #     return self.queryset
    # else:
    return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)

# DELETE TESTDATATHREE ID
def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object()
    self.perform_destroy(instance)
    return Response("Deleted Successfully", status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

I am guessing I need to change something in the views class, but not sure what. Appreciate any help here.

Example of output in Postman:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Remove the default='-1' from `sdgdata = models.OneToOneField(TestDataTwo, related_name="testdatatwo", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=-1)`. That's causing the error.

Comment: Hey Ene P. I've tried that, I just get a null error if I do that. 

IntegrityError at /api/testdatathree
null value in column "sdgdata_id" of relation "api_testdatathree" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (3, h, null, 4).

Any other ideas?

Comment: Pass `"sdgdata_id": 12` in your request?

Comment: @aaron that works if I hardcode sdgdata_id like so: 

 # CREATE NEW TESTDATATHREE ROW FOR USER
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user, testdatatwo_id=12)

But I want to refer to it dynamically like I did to the user. I am unsure of the syntax on how to do so.

Comment: It should be passed in the request, just as the user is the logged in user of the request. How would the application know which `sdgdata` to set?